# Massively parallel application: what about several 8 bits cores for non-vector IA applications?

Tags: multithreading, artificial-intelligence, parallel-processing

I was thinking (oh god, it starts badly) about neuron networks and how it is not possible to simulate those because they require many atomic operation at the same time (here meaning simultaneously), because that's how neurons are faster: they are many to compute stuff.

Since our processors are 32 bits so they can compute a significantly larger band (meaning a lot of different atomic numbers, being floating points or integers), the frequency race is also over and manufacturers start shipping multicore processors, requiring developpers to implement multithreading in their application.

I was also thinking about the most important difference between computers and brains; brains use a lot of neurons, while computers use precision at a high frequency: that's why it seems harder or impossible to simulate an real time AI with the current processor model.

Since 32bits/64bits chips also take a great deal of transistors and since AI doesn't require vector/floating point precision, would it be a good idea to have many more 8bits cores on a single processor, like 100 or 1000 for example since they take much less room (I don't work at intel or AMD so I don't know how they design their processors, it's just a wild guess), to plan for those kind of AI simulations ?

I don't think it would only serve AI research though, because I don't know how webservers can really take advantage of 64 bits processors (strings use 8bits), Xeon processors are only different considering their cache size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is already available by means of multimedia instruction sets. It turns out that computer graphics needs also many parallel operations on bytes or even half-bytes. So the CPUs started growing vector operations ([SSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions), MMX, etc); more recently, graphic processors have opened up to general purpose computing ([GPGPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPGPU)).

I think you are mistaken in assuming that neuronal processing is *not* a vector operation: many AI neuronal networks heavily rely on vector and matrix operations.

Comment: What about branch caching ? I heard that GPUs are much less optimal for computing branching code, meaning everything containing condition checking (if, switch, etc). Does those types of GPGPU are also optimal for that kind of programming paradigm ? Maybe I was told incorrectly, but it seems massively parallel graphic processors are bad at branching.

Comment: It's true that GPUs are bad at branching. Fortunately, for a neural network, you don't need branching.

Comment: Can you explain how an AI doesn't need branching ? Branching seems important in every aspect of computing.

Comment: A neural network typically computes its output using a straight-forward formula from the inputs. These are typically continuous functions, which don't require branching to be computed. The net does this for all neurons (ideally in parallel), and then cycles - which is the only control action, but it happens simultaneously for all neurons, to the same instruction.